# UDK How To Make Class

Tags: unreal, udk

I am currently using UDK because my PC has 32 bit CPU & doesn't support UE4,..

I Just Started Learning UDK From Yours Tutorial...

Que-> I made 12 Tube light (mesh) in udk with there own point light Bulb,,,So I Want to Destroy Each Tube Light and There Own Blub...

With Plasma and beam Guns...

When The Health Of Tube light goes Specific Range Then It Destroy....But In Kismet How To Code That For Having All TubeLights Have There Own Health....In UE4 If We Write Script In Actor Class And Copy The Object Then It's Does But,In UDK How To Make The Class...For This TubeLight.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in UE3, Kismet was equivalent to Level Blueprints in UE4. There is no way to "create a class" using Kismet.

In UE3, you would either need to copy-paste the visual script for each light. You could possibly use a kismet function and pass in the tube light to eliminate some of the duplication.

To get the equivalent of blueprint classes in UE4, you'd have to utilize UE3's UnrealScript scripting language, and write out the functionality in script.

Specifically (it's been a while so I might be missing something in this process):
- Create a new package to hold your script files.
- Create a new script class and have it inherit from, at least Actor.
- Give it a StaticMeshComponent. (Alternatively, perhaps you could inherit from StaticMeshActor instead of Actor)
- Give it a PointLightComponent.
- Give it a health variable.
- Override TakeDamage() to handle reducing the health and destruction.

This is just a rough overview to get you started. Good luck!